# Changing color used in storyboards?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-style

I am in a situation where I have defined 3 colors in my program. They are defined in `App.xaml` as such:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="Aero">
                <Color x:Key="AccentColor">#3399ff</Color>
                <Color x:Key="AccentDarkColor">#236bb2</Color>
                <Color x:Key="AccentDarkerColor">#1e5b99</Color>

                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentBrush" Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentDarkBrush" Color="{DynamicResource AccentDarkColor}" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentDarkerBrush" Color="{DynamicResource AccentDarkerColor}" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now, I want these colors to be changeable, so there are areas of my program where I change them programmatically:

```
Application.Current.Resources["AccentColor"] = color;
Application.Current.Resources["AccentDarkColor"] = color;
Application.Current.Resources["AccentDarkerColor"] = color;
```

This however poses a problem, since I also have storyboards defined in my application that allow the application to fade (via a `ColorAnimation`) from one color to another (for instance fading from `AccentColor` to `AccentDarkColor`).

When these storyboards do this, they use a `StaticResource` since a `DynamicResource` can't be used (because the `Storyboard` has to be freezable) for WPF to do its thing.

### What did I try?

I tried moving the storyboards to `App.xaml` as well, and then (in my `BeginStoryboard` refer to a `DynamicResource` of the storyboard:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{DynamicResource BackgroundToAccentBorderToAccentDarkTransitionStoryboard}" />
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
     </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

However, when I then programmatically change the storyboards, they don't change when the `DataTrigger` gets re-executed, despite it being a `DynamicResource`.

What can I do?

Comment: A simple workaround would be having different ResourceDictionaries, containing the color and the storyboard, and replace them as a whole.

Comment: The thing is that the color is dynamic, and must be set programmatically. I change it when the Aero color of Windows changes, and I change them based on that color.